# NFS share connection wait

Tags: networking, mount, nfs, nas

I've got a Synology NAS at home and I auto-mount the NFS shared folders from it on my laptop. However, when I am using the laptop outside my house, it takes it too long to boot up and I suspect that it is because it tries to mount the NFS shares. I wonder if it is possible to set it up in a way when the laptop does not try to mount the shares if the home network is not present. Or that it would give up attempts to mount the shares quicker?

Comment: You could set it up so that it only tries to mount the share on demand, using `autofs` - see for example [NFS mount with fstab vs autofs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/266199/65304)

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. Is there a good tutorial for how set it up?

Comment: Take a look here [EXAMPLE: Auto-mounting an NFS share](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs#EXAMPLE:_Auto-mounting_an_NFS_share) and post back with specific questions if you have them. (It's a little out of date - you should probably be using `systemd` commands to manage the service e.g. `sudo systemctl reload autofs.service` in place of `sudo reload autofs`).

Comment: OK, it works now! Is there any other way to access the shares rather than typing [code]ls ~/NAS/<share>[/code] in the Terminal, because the shares do not show up in the Nautilus.